# Connecting to FreeNFS from CentOS 6

Tags: mount, nfs

I'm trying to mount a [FreeNFS](http://freenfs.sourceforge.net/) share located on my Windows 7 host, under my CentOS 6 virtual machine inside VirtualBox.

The networking between the host and the guest is working fine, and I've been successful in mounting an NFS share provided by a different Windows software ([winnfsd](http://sourceforge.net/projects/winnfsd/), with I'm not using anymore because of a different issue).

The mount command I'm using is:

```
mount -v -t nfs -o vers=3 192.168.56.1:/ /mnt/www/
```

And the result is:

```
mount.nfs: timeout set for Wed Nov 19 14:50:02 2014
mount.nfs: trying text-based options 'nfsvers=3,addr=192.168.56.1'
mount.nfs: prog 100003, trying vers=3, prot=6
mount.nfs: trying 192.168.56.1 prog 100003 vers 3 prot TCP port 2049
mount.nfs: portmap query failed: RPC: Authentication error
mount.nfs: access denied by server while mounting 192.168.56.1:/
```

I've tried with `vers=2`, not much better:

```
mount.nfs: timeout set for Wed Nov 19 14:54:43 2014
mount.nfs: trying text-based options 'vers=2,addr=192.168.56.1'
mount.nfs: prog 100003, trying vers=2, prot=6
mount.nfs: portmap query retrying: RPC: Program not registered
mount.nfs: prog 100003, trying vers=2, prot=17
mount.nfs: portmap query failed: RPC: Program not registered
mount.nfs: requested NFS version or transport protocol is not supported
```

And `vers=4`, not supported by FreeNFS but just for information:

```
mount.nfs: timeout set for Wed Nov 19 14:56:40 2014
mount.nfs: trying text-based options 'vers=4,addr=192.168.56.1,clientaddr=192.168.56.220'
mount.nfs: mount(2): Permission denied
mount.nfs: access denied by server while mounting 192.168.56.1:/
```

I've also tried the following, gathered from forum posts here and there:

- `nfsvers=x` instead of `vers=x`
- `sec=none`
- `nolock`
- stopping `iptables` and `ip6tables` services on the guest
- disabling the firewall on the host
- ensuring that the `rpcbind` service is running on the guest
- adding `rpcbind : ALL` to `/etc/hosts.allow` on the guest

But none of these solutions made any difference.

I'm surprised it's so difficult to mount a FreeNFS share. I've read [this question on unix.stackexchange](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/120875/nfs-shares-windows-using-freenfs-but-connecting-on-linux) and this forum post: [Anyone have FreeNFS working?](http://forum.kodi.tv/showthread.php?tid=166599) but it doesn't seem that in either case, the OP got it working eventually.

I'm kind of desperate for solutions now, **how to mount this NFS share under my CentOS 6 guest?**

Comment: In [this thread](http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/120875/nfs-shares-windows-using-freenfs-but-connecting-on-linux), authentication had to be disabled to get it working. The final command, adapted to your case, would be something like: `sudo mount -v -t nfs -o nfsvers=3,sec=none 192.168.56.1:/ /nas`.

Comment: @harrymc I link to this thread in my question, and mention that I tried `sec=none` already!

Comment: Sorry, I commented too quickly. More to try: (1) Disabling in CentOS selinux and firewall (if enabled; also Windows firewall), (2) Change VirtualBox networking to Bridge mode (if NAT), (3) Ensure portmap and nfslock services are started on CentOS, (4) What is the output of `showmount -e 192.168.56.1` (5) Some people [claim](http://www.mede8erforum.com/index.php/topic,10625.0.html) that [HaneWIN](http://www.hanewin.net/nfs-e.htm) is much better than FreeNFS.